# GraphQL is missing a service layer that

Tags: graphql, mutation

So I've been building my new app with GraphQL. It works great with modifying my apps models. But I find there's a serious hole in the way GraphQL works that REST API's handle better. For example, here's my use case:

- When a form on my frontend is submitted, it creates a mutation:  `createFoo`.

This alone works great. It creates a new Foo object in my database. But now I have this additional use case:

- When the form is submitted, I want to hit a service that not only creates a Foo object in my database, but I also want to hit a third party API (some service I'm using) notifying me of the new creation.

How do I achieve this? With a REST API I would simply add that additional task as part of the API endpoint. With GraphQL there is no concept of a service layer that does other business logic. Should I do this in the mutation? It seems like a weird side effect to add some additional business logic to a mutation that creates an object..How are these things thought of in GraphQL world?